# docker images are stored in root user thus consuming my disk space

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

Hi my server is configured such that the free space for root user in it is very less. However the user created(suppose **user1**) has lot of space.
The docker images which are getting created by docker are saved in the root user thus consuming space and making my jobs to fail.How can i make docker images use **user1**?

Do i need to restart the registry in anyway?

I am unable to understand how to use docker groups and -G tag for this purpose.

Can i mention something in dockerfile and make images up using **user1** ?

Comment: The docker daemon needs to mount filesystems and do various things that require being root, so I guess you should have space for you root user. Read also "Running docker entirely as non-root" https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linked /var to /user1/var.

The mounts and the volumes stay the same.

I did this:

```
`telinit 1 
cp -pR /var /user1/var 
mv /var /var.old 
ln -s /user1/var /var 
telinit 2`
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the -g option on the daemon process. Can be used to locate the docker home on an alternative disk volume.

Explained in the following documentation links:

- http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#daemon
- http://docs.docker.com/articles/systemd/#custom-docker-daemon-options